# getting an alphabet split

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I've been trying to write code which seperates the age (digits) from name (alphabets) and then compares it to a pre-defined list and if it doesn't match with the list then it sends out an error but instead of getting (for example) alex:error, i'm getting a:error l:error e:error x:error, that is it's splitting the words to its alphabets. Here's the code:

```
from string import digits



print("Enter name and age(seperated by a comma):")
names=input("Data:")
names1=names.strip().replace(" ","").split(',')

removed_digits=str.maketrans('','',digits)
names2=names.translate(removed_digits)
lst1=['john','cena','rey']
print(names)
print(names1)
print(names2)

for name in names2:
    if name not in lst1:
        print(f"{name}:Not Matching to our database.")
```

the output is :

```
Enter name and age(seperated by a comma):
Data:alex 12, john 13
alex 12, john 13
['alex12', 'john13']
alex , john 
a:Not Matching to our database.
l:Not Matching to our database.
e:Not Matching to our database.
x:Not Matching to our database.
 :Not Matching to our database.
,:Not Matching to our database.
 :Not Matching to our database.
j:Not Matching to our database.
o:Not Matching to our database.
h:Not Matching to our database.
n:Not Matching to our database.
 :Not Matching to our database.
```

thanks for helping me out! Also I'd love if someone was to explain why my code wasn't working, I referred to pythontutor but still wasn't able to figure out the bug myself!

Comment: `str.translate(...)` returns a string not a list, so basically you're looping over a string in the end.

Comment: @Jan hey i tried converting my list to a string but that didnt work as well and it showed some weird output,need advice

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your names2 variable as its a string type. You need to conver it to a list and append each name to it after str.translate(). Here is the modified code.

```
names2=[name.translate(removed_digits) for name in names1]
```

I hope your problem will solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
names=input("Data:")
names1=names.strip().split(',')  #split names

for name in names1:
    names2 = name.strip().split(' ')  #split name and digit
    if names2[0] not in lst1:
        print(f"{name}:Not Matching to our database.")
```

Comment: but it wont seperate the age from the name :/

Comment: `names2[1]` contains the corresponding age

Comment: i get your logic but what if there isnt a space between name and age like ravi12,abhi23 etcetc